Latex3: why are spaces consumed before regex matches
I am trying to extract parts of a string using regular expressions.
For example, from a string input John Smith (role: proof reader) I would like to extract John Smith and proof reader.
Here's my attempt
\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_foo_seq

\regex_extract_once:nnN { ([\w\s]+)\(role:\s*([\w\s]+)\) } { {John Smith (role: proof reader)} } \l_foo_seq 

\newcommand{\showme}{
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_foo_seq {
        {##1,} \par
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

The information I want is identified but the spaces are being removed. The output of \showme is
JohnSmith(role:proofreader),
JohnSmith,
proofreader,

I noticed that I can take the space-matching out of my regex and nothing changes, i.e.: ([\w]+)\(role:([\w]+)\). So, I guess the spaces are removed before \regex_extract_once:nnN does its stuff. I hoped that the enclosing braces would have presented the string as a single token with the spaces intact.
I'm a beginner at this. Advice and explanation would be welcome, as I'm finding the docs a bit hard to get into.

You shouldn't use \l_foo_seq. I don't know whether foo is the module name or the description, but it is missing the other one.

Spaces within the \ExplSyntax ... \ExplSyntaxOff "environment" are ignored. If you need an explicit space, you need to use ~.  So the example code you give works if we replaces the spaces with ~. But in practice you would probably want the command to be part of a macro used in the document, in which case the spaces will be preserved as you expect:
Edit: Following up on cfr's comment, I've changed your sequence name to conform to the recommended Expl3 naming conventions, adding username as a substitute for the module part of the naming convention.
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_blair_foo_seq
\regex_extract_once:nnN { ([\w\s]+)\(role:\s*([\w\s]+)\) } { {John~Smith~(role:~proof~reader)} } \l_blair_foo_seq 

\NewDocumentCommand{\extract}{m} {
\regex_extract_once:nnN { ([\w\s]+)\(role:\s*([\w\s]+)\) } {#1}  \l_blair_foo_seq }

\newcommand{\showme}{
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_blair_foo_seq {
        {##1,} \par
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\showme
\extract{John Smith (role: proof reader)}
\showme
\end{document}



It shouldn't really be \l_foo_seq, though.

@cfr Good point. I've updated the answer.
